# Finding place to insert new element in sorted range

Tags: algorithm

What is the best algorithm (with O(log n) time complexity) for finding position to insert new element in a sorted range?

For example let's assume that we have a following range:

> 2 3 15 19 25 36 73 103

I want to insert a new value to that range, for example 39. To find a position of where this value should be inserted I have to go through the whole range what gives a O(n) complexity. Is there a better method?

Comment: This is just a search in a sorted array and there are books full of algorithms for the purpose.  You could do worse than start learning about *binary search*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the **binary search** here to find the position of the **next greater element** than the element to insert. Below is the c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v = {2 ,3 ,15 ,19 ,25 , 36, 45, 73 ,103};


    int start = 0, end = v.size()-1, mid = (start+end)/2, elem = 104, pos = 0;

    while(start<=end){

        if(v[mid] < elem){
            start = mid+1;
            pos = start;
        }
        else if(v[mid] > elem)
        {
            end = mid-1;
            pos = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            pos = -1;
            break;
        }

        mid = (start+end)/2;

    }

    if(pos != -1)
        cout<<"position: "<<pos<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"item already present"<<endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Input: 2
Output: item already present

Input: 39
Output: 6

Input: 1
Output: 0

Input: 104
Output: 9
```

Complexity : **O(logN)**

Answer (score 2):

In Java you have a method [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int)) that returns a positive integer or zero if the element already exists or a negative integer if it doesn't exist. The negative integer is returned as *(-(insertion point) - 1)* that means you need to calculate the insertion point as `-returned_index-1` if the returned value is < 0

```
int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 15, 19, 25, 36, 73, 103};
int i = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 39);
System.out.println( i < 0 ? -i-1 : i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (`python`):

```py
def insEl(arr, el):
    l=len(arr)
    if(arr[l-1]<el):
        return arr+[el]
    if(arr[(l-1)//2]<el):
        return arr[:(l-1)//2]+insEl(arr[(l-1)//2:], el)
    else:
        return insEl(arr[:(l-1)//2], el)+arr[(l-1)//2:]
```

Call:

```py
>>> arr=[2, 3, 15, 19, 25, 36, 73, 103]
>>> print(insEl(arr, 39))

[2, 3, 15, 19, 25, 36, 39, 73, 103]
```

It's `O(log(n))` if I recall correctly.